# Swagger Spring mvc reponsebody

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

Is there a way to present the request body of a complex object in swagger with each field having it's input?

In simple words if one of my apis expects a Person (suppose it has just a firstname/lastname) as @RequestBody then the only way to provide this Person with swagger would be to give the entire json of Person. Is there a way to enable each separate field to have it's separate input for firstname/lastname for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotate your Operation using `@ModelAttribute`it should do exactly what you're looking for

For e.g. instead of

```java
public void updatePersonName(@RequestBody Person person) { ... }
```

Use this

```
public void updatePersonName(@ModelAttribute Person person) { ... }
```

The @ModelAttribute will expand the primitive properties and provide fields for entering in the first name and last name in the swagger ui. The equivalent of that operation is

```java
public void updatePersonName(@RequestParam String firstName, 
                             @RequestParam String lastName) { ... }
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not happen. I raised an issue for that also

Comment: Link? It should work, with the caveat that your model properties need to be *bean properties* with getters and setters.

Comment: what if instead of setters there is the constructor - the class is Immutable. Is that supposed to work?

Comment: this works for setters/getters indeed; but it breaks immutability of course. Not sure I'm ok with that

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using swagger with the default swagger UI and I don't think it's possible unless you change the swagger UI code. But a quite convenient solution is to define the type of your parameter and then provide the model for that type. For instance

```
 "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "body",
                    "description": "A Person",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "Person"
                }
            ]
```

And then

```
 "definitions": {
    "Person": {
      "properties": {
            "firstName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
      }
   }
```

This way the model appears in the UI and you can easily copy it to the request body textbox and fill it with content manually.